# MySQL keeps locking up after performing thousands of constant inserts for a minute

Tags: java, mysql, jdbctemplate

I have a java app that runs inside tomcat 7 and performs continuous nonstop rapid inserts into a MySQL database (5.1.73-community on windows 10)using Spring JDBCTemplate.

After about a minute of constant inserts, the mysql database service becomes inaccessible from not only my java app in tomcat, but also I'm unable to log into mysql from a 3rd party client like Squirrel.

As soon as I kill tomcat, I am able to log into mysql from squirrel or restart my app which runs fine again...until the constant inserts again lock up the database.

Here is the code that performs the inserts

```
  public int insertRecord(final String sql,final Object[] paramArray, KeyHolder keyHolder) {

    Integer retStatus = jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() { 

      public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) 
      throws SQLException { 
          String[] keyColNames=new String[1];
          PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql,keyColNames); 
          if(paramArray!=null){
            int size=paramArray.length;
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
              ps.setObject(i+1, paramArray[i]);
            }
          }

          return ps; 
        } 
      }, keyHolder);  
    return retStatus;
  }
```

What can I do in my code to avoid locking up the database?

Comment: I'm only guessing, but it sounds like you (or maybe Spring JDBC Template) are creating many concurrent database connections and you are probably reaching the available limit and I'm also guessing that these database connections are either not released at all or not released quickly enough.

Comment: I changed my datasource from the Spring DriverManagerDataSource to the Apache dbcp2 BasicDataSource, which seems to have fixed the issue